# Appending a list in python + Validation of inputted data

Tags: python, list, validation, append

I'm having trouble adding items to a list from a user's input, I think you can see what I'm trying to do here, I want the user to be able to add items to a list, and have it displayed afterwards. Criteria: It must contain a FOR loop and some form of data validation.

```
def main():
    num=int(input("How many values would you like in your list?"))
    for x in range(num)
        myList=[]
        newValue=input("Enter the text you would like to add")
        myList.append(newValue)
    print(myList)
```

Comment: So, what's your question? One obvious issue is that myList needs to be defined before the loop rather than inside, but what are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem

You are initializing the list every time as `myList = []` inside the loop. Whatever data you appended is lost.

Also, `:` is missing after `range(num)`.

> Solution

Simply initialize it outside the loop.

```
def main():
    num=int(input("How many values would you like in your list?"))
    myList=[] # This needs to be initialized outside the loop 
    for x in range(num):
        newValue=input("Enter the text you would like to add")
        myList.append(newValue)
    print(myList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
def main():
    num=int(raw_input("How many values would you like in your list? "))
    myList=[]
    for x in range(num):
        newValue = raw_input("Enter the text you would like to add ")
        myList.append(newValue)
    print(myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem in your code is that for needs : at the end.

But the main one is that you are reseting your myList to an empty list at the start of each iteration... as a result, anything you input is going to be appended in an empty list (so the result of a single-valued list).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have multiple mistakes:

- You are missing a colon in the `for` loop
- Since you reassign `myList` to an empty list every single iteration of the `for` loop, the list will only have one value in the end
- You actually need to call the function

Thus the code becomes:

```
def main():
    num=int(input("How many values would you like in your list?"))
    myList = []               # Create the list here instead
    for x in range(num):      # Colon is needed
        newValue = raw_input("Enter the text you would like to add: ")
        myList.append(newValue)
    print(myList)

main()                        # Call the function
```